# Compile PySNMP with cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pysnmp

I write a small python 3.3 script that query devices by pySNMP.

I compiled the script with `cx_freeze` (No errors) but I have a problem:
When I ran the script I had an error regarding MIB files (*.py) not present in the library.zip, so I manually copied the MIBs in the library and the script worked fine. Then I tried to add the libraries during compilation adding (example):

`zipinclude = [("C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages/pysnmp-4.2.4-py3.3.egg/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.py","pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.py")]`

to the setup.py script in `cx_freeze`, but even if the MIBs(.py) were present in the library.zip after compilation, the script didn't work until I manually copied the MIBs to library.zip (overwriting the ones included by cx_freeze).

Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: cx_Freeze seems to have problems with `.egg` installations. Try installing it so you just get a `pysnmp` folder in site-packages.